# trying to remove an item from a database

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Sorry If I'm not explaining this very well. I'm trying to delete from a database using this button press, but whenever I try to delete it will only delete the first item in the database. I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with the ID I'm getting. Can anyone spot any obvious issues I'm missing here?

```
Button Press:

    tasksDOM.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
      const el = e.target
      if (el.parentElement.classList.contains('delete-btn')) {
        loadingDOM.style.visibility = 'visible'
        const id = el.parentElement.dataset.id
        try {
          await axios.delete(`/tm/v1/tasks/${id}`)
          showTasks()
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      }
      loadingDOM.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    })
    

Delete:

    app.delete("/tm/v1/tasks/:id", async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const response = await Task.findOneAndDelete({ id });
        res.status(200).json({ msg: 'deleted' });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ msg: error });
      }; 
    });
```

Comment: You need to pass params as object. axios.delete(`/tm/v1/tasks/`, {id: 'asd'})

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions -

```
1. const response = await Task.findByIdAndDelete(id);
2. const response = await Task.findOneAndDelete({ _id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) });
```

> Don't forget to import `mongoose` for second method.

**Explanation** -

In your code `findOneAndDelete` is taking `id` as argument which doesn't exist for mongoose so default, its deleting the first entry so you need to use `_id` here. Second thing is, `id` param is string type and `_id` is ObjectId so it will not match. To match this, you need to convert this string value to mongoose ObjectId.

`findByIdAndDelete` works with string value as well!